# Get SUM data for each month for one years interval for chart.js

Tags: mysql

I have a table with IP accounting data,

I am wanting to get the `SUM(bytes)` for each month(jan, feb, mar...) for the interval of one year from the current day

```
column: bytes <-- bytes

column: timeanddate <-- timestamp
```

My query:

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(bytes) FROM ip_accounting);
```

Please help.

Comment: Look into `GROUP BY` and MySQL's date functions.

Comment: I have looked into that but I am a bit stuck

Comment: What don't you understand about `GROUP BY`? Post the query you wrote using it and we can advise from there.

Comment: `SELECT SUM(bytes) FROM ip_accounting WHERE timeanddate=DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR) GROUP BY MONTH(timeanddate)` still stuck on knowing how to get data for each month and I'm not even sure if this query is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the answer I was looking for

```
SELECT 
    SUM(download_bytes) as download_bytes, 
    SUM(upload_bytes) as upload_bytes, 
    SUM(download_bytes + upload_bytes) as total_bytes, 
    DAY(date) as day, 
    MONTHNAME(date) as month 
FROM 
    traffic_counters 
LEFT JOIN services ON traffic_counters.service_id = services.id 
WHERE 
    date >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
GROUP BY 
    MONTH(date),
    DAY(date)
ORDER BY 
    MONTH(date), 
    DAY(date)
```